# Some %r format starts and ends with a double quote instead of a single quote

Tags: python

I have two similar python codes.

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
print formatter % (
    "I had this thing",
    "That you could type upright",
    "But it didn't sing",
    "So I said goodnight"
)
print formatter % (
    "hi!",
    "My name is __!",
    "nice to meet you!",
    "thank you!"
)
```

Other is printed as ' ', but the only third phrase is printed as "But it didn't sing" in the first code.
why does it result in Double quotes?

result :

'I had this thing.' 'That you could type up right.' "But it didn't sing." 'So I said goodnight.'

Comment: `didn't` in third line contains a single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that's because the [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) function returns the printable representation of an object. I mean, in the other phrases you are not using the single quote character `'`, so it doesn't need to use to double quote `"`. This is equivalent to say:

```
'But it didn\'t sing'
```

However, Python interpreter will try to follow the [Python Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (use to simplest option). In this case the simplest option is to use the double quotes and put the single quote inside. Try for instance this phrase:

```
"My name is \"__!\""
```

You will see that it's printing: `'My name is "__!"'` (the simplest option)

Comment: Again, by best practices you should always use the single quote. That means that, given that "I had this thing" is using unnecessary double quotes , the interpreter will use single quotes, meaning 'I had this thing'. In the third case, you put "But it didn't sing." In this case double quotes are necessary, because you have a single quote in the middle. Usually your always use single quote and when you need something special you use double quotes, and that's what the interpreter is doing